# How do I unsubscribe from a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm adding a subscription feature where users can subscribe/unsubscribe to/from a genre. I've been able to create subscription but I don't know how to unsubscribe if a user has already subscribed.

I used has_many :through relationship for this feature. I didn't post the details of that because SO text editor thinks I've too much code written.

```
subscription table

create_table "subscriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "genre_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["genre_id"], name: "index_subscriptions_on_genre_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_subscriptions_on_user_id"
 end

subscriptions_controller.rb

class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
    @subscription.user_id = current_user.id
    @subscription.save

    redirect_to genre_path(@subscription.genre_id)
end

def destroy
    if @subscription.destroy
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
        flash[:danger] = %Q[<i class="fa fa-trash"></i> You have successfully 
    unsubscribed from this genre.]
    end
end

private

def subscription_params
    params.require(:subscription).permit(:genre_id)
end
end

genres_controller.rb

def show
      @subscriber_count = @genre.subscribers.count
      @is_subscribed = user_signed_in? ? Subscription.where(genre_id: @genre.id, 
   user_id: current_user.id).any? : false
      @subscription = Subscription.new
      @sub_genres = Subscription.where(genre_id: @genre)
end

genres/show

<div class="subscribe">
        <% if @is_subscribed %>
            <%= link_to @subscription, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm" 
        do %>
                <%= fa_icon "times" %> Unsubscribe
            <% end %>
        <% else %>
            <%= render partial: "genres/subscribe", locals: { genre_id: @genre.id } 
        %>
        <% end %>
</div>

genres/_subscribe

<%= form_with(model: @subscription, local: true) do |form| %>
    <%= form.hidden_field :genre_id, value: genre_id %>
    <%= form.submit "Subscribe", class: "btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

routes.rb

resources :subscriptions
```

When I click on delete link, I get the error:

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/subscriptions"
```

Comment: Your Unsuscribe `link_to` helper is using a `post` method instead of `delete` .

Comment: After changing to :delete, I get the error `No route matches [DELETE] "/genre_subscriptions"`

Comment: It looks like you’re using genre_subscriptions_path (plural). The standard route to destroy includes an id: genre_subscription_path(id)

Comment: Also, is subscriptions inside a ‘resources :genre do’ block?

Comment: You have `@subscription = Subscription.new` and then you use that `@subscription` variable on the link to delete it (it's a new subscription, you cannot delete that one)

Comment: @AJFaraday, no it isn't nested. It's just resources :subscriptions

Comment: @AJFaraday, it was initially a custom route as in resources :subscriptions, path: "genre_subscriptions".

Comment: What adjustments do I need to make to my codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to delete a new subscription.

You have this:

```
@subscription = Subscription.new
```

and then you have this:

```
= link_to @subscription, method: :delete
```

that subscription cannot be deleted because it's not a persisted subscription.

You have to use the actual subscription record that you want to delete, so change your controller to:

```
@subscription = current_user ? current_user.subscriptions.where(genre: @genre).first : nil # get the subscription for the current user and genre
@subscription ||= Subscription.new # if nil, use a new subscription
```

Then in your view you can do:

```
<% if @subscription.persisted? %>
  <%= link_to @subscription, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm" do %>
    <%= fa_icon "times" %> Unsubscribe
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= render partial: "genres/subscribe", locals: { genre_id: @genre.id } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks especially for explaining. Now I get it.